# Show yticks only within the chosen xlim

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to tie the y-axis to xlim to show only the ticks that fall within the chosen xlim (i.e. the y-axis should only include the ticks with blue bars, and remove the other ticks with blank values). Image attached.
Including full code for replication. Thanks

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import string

k = 5
N = 100

users = pd.DataFrame({'freq' : np.random.randint(k, k + 100 , size=N),
              'id' : pd.Series(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(N)) })


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.barh(users.id, users.freq)
labels = ax.get_xticklabels()
plt.setp(labels, rotation = 45, horizontalalignment = 'right')
ax.set(xlim = [90, 100], xlabel = 'Frequency', ylabel = 'ID',
title = 'Match')
ax.get_yticks()
ax.legend(labels = ('Match'), loc = 'upper right')
```

Image: Show only yticks in relation to xlim, remove the rest

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Manually" creating the dataframe with the summed frequencies, then filtering and plotting it seems to be a good approach.

To get all the users with a frequency of at least 90, use

```
grouped_users.loc[grouped_users.freq >= 90]
```

To also limit the maximum, a boolean *and* (`&`) and brackets are needed:

```
grouped_users.loc[(grouped_users.freq >= 90) & (grouped_users.freq <= 100)]
```

Some demo code to compare with the original plot:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string

np.random.seed(12345)
k = 5
N = 100
users = pd.DataFrame({'freq': np.random.randint(k, k + 100, size=N),
                      'id': np.random.choice(list(string.ascii_uppercase), N)})
x0 = 90
x1 = 100
grouped_users = users.groupby('id')[['id', 'freq']].sum()
grouped_users_filtered = grouped_users.loc[grouped_users.freq >= x0]

fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
ax0.barh(users.id, users.freq)
ax1.barh(grouped_users_filtered.index, grouped_users_filtered.freq)

for ax in (ax0, ax1):
    ax.set(xlim=[x0, x1], xlabel='Frequency', ylabel='ID', title='Match')
plt.show()
```

[image: result]

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. (I was hoping to find something like (set_yticks = xlim) but it probably doesn't exist. The summing and filtering you did produces the desired bar graph. Thanks a lot.